# Get POST parameter from NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, nsurlrequest

Is it possible to retrieve the value of a POST parameter from a NSURLRequest in the method;

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Is so, how is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be possible with the class method of NSURLProtocol:

```
+ (id)propertyForKey:(NSString *)key inRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

So if you have got a property named "place" you could try that:

```
[NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"place" inRequest:myRequestObject]
```

**[EDIT]**
If you want to retrieve all properties, I think you have to use `- (NSData *)HTTPBody`
 from `NSURLRequest` and then parse the property names/values yourself. Should be no problem with urldecode and RegEx.

Comment: Is is possible to get all available keys?

Comment: The propertyForKey method returns null, even when the parameter is  in the HTTPBody

Comment: I don't think propertyForKey works in this case. I'm getting nil back as well. Getting HTTPBody and parsing yourself, however should work.

Comment: This will show all post params: `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)[[request HTTPBody] bytes]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURLRequest *request = ...
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request HTTPBody] options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: Yes this works but there may be an edge case in which an NSDictionary is not returned so you may want to check the returned type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910312/take-post-request-from-webview what is the return type of this ?